# Hyperledger fabric base image protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable

Tags: hyperledger

For the devenv, when run vagrant up, got protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable error.

```
==> default: protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
==> default: --go_out
==> default: : 
==> default: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
==> default: make: 
==> default: *** [consensus/pbft/messages.pb.go] Error 1
```

Comment: context ? what is the provisioning you run etc etc

Comment: @FrédéricHenri

Vagrant Installed Version: 1.8.5  
Go version 1.6.3
Hyperledger fabric commit # a087441
MacOSX El Captain

I just run the vagrant up from the devenv folder. 
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv/

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has been addressed by the Hyperledger team https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/725/

If you pull latest changes from their gerrit mirror, you should have latest changes and should be able to provision without error.

Comment: Thanks, I have confirmed this morning. Vagrant up is fine after reverting back the protobuf upgrade. However, there is another issue arises that I will open in a separate thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue in windows environment,

```
src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\core\crypto\attributes\attributes.go:28:2: no buildable Go source files in D:\GOProjects\src\github.com\hyperledger\fabric\core\crypto\attributes\proto
```

So I looked at the cache of this directory on github, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/core/crypto/attributes/proto

and realized that there used to be a file with `.pb.go` extension which was not there after the upgrade from protobuff from 3-beta to 3. The way i fixed it is by downloading the `.pb.go` from Google cache.

I also wrote an email to the developer and got the following response,

> Can you run "make protos" in the folder where the main Makefile is
>   present?

**Edit:**

They have reverted the upgrade back to previous one,
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/af5f75d3fb52ee5cd607abfef4324fc049153268
and should work fine now.